# Tmux open 4 panes and set each of those panes to a specific directory

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, tmux

Is there a way to create a script to have tmux open with 4 panes and each of those panes opens into a specific directory?

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Both `tmux new-window` and `tmux split-window` come with a `-c` option that can specify a start-directory. So you can do a new-window followed by three consecutive split-windows to get your four pane window. You can also provide an additional `tmux select-layout` command to setup the wanted layout of those four panes.

## example

```
tmux new-window -c ~
tmux split-window -h -c /tmp
tmux split-window -v -c /
tmux select-pane -t 1
tmux split-window -v -c /home
tmux select-pane -t 1
```